# Open new windows in the same position as the parent window

Tags: google-chrome

I want Chrome to open new windows in the same position as the original window I opened the new window from. Chrome pushes new windows down and to the right a few pixels by default, but does use the same window dimensions as the parent window.

This must be an application-specific implementation; opening new windows from Windows Explorer for example uses a much wider spacing for each new window.

How can I configure Chrome to stop using a diagonal offset altogether?

[image]

Comment: Why not just use tabs instead?

Comment: Windows serve a different purpose than tabs. There are many different reasons to open windows, and this discussion is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Yes, I voted to close my question as a duplicate after realizing this was a dupe.